# Convert ASCII to its decimal value

Tags: ascii

There is online tool that can convert text to ASCII such as [this one](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/). Would it be possible to do the same thing in Ubuntu/Linux?

E.g.

```
Input data: abc

Output as ASCII: 097 098 099
```

Comment: An `apt-cache search ascii decimal` provided "*ascii2binary - Convert between ASCII, hexadecimal and binary representations*" as the first option (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ascii2binary.1.html shows decimal as an option). I use `hexdump` myself (but I want it from files) but use the program/options that best suits your needs (`apt-cache` search showed a number for my release; if none suitable I'd likely search for snap next (`snap search`)...

Comment: You want to convert from ASCII symbol to its decimal value. The complete table is on `man ascii` ([or just `ascii`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15149/209677)). [Or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/890262/4970442): ASCII to decimal `printf "%d\n" \'a`, decimal to ASCII `printf '%b' $(printf '\\%03o' "97")`

Comment: Take a look at the old standby, od.  Your ascii to decimal would be echo abc | od -td1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the old standby, `od`. Your ASCII to decimal would be:

```
echo -n abc | od -td1
```

See the [man page for `od`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/od.1.html), or "octal dump",

```
man od
```

For the many options in converting input to other forms -- hex, decimal, ASCII, char, etc.

Comment: Maybe we should say `echo -n abc | od -td1`. Otherwise `od` will show the decimal value of newline too (which is 10).

Comment: Cool. It works. I was trying to up vote your answer but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert from ASCII symbol to its decimal value.

The complete table is on man `ascii` ([or just `ascii`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15149/209677)).

**ASCII to decimal**: "a" → "97"

```sh
printf "%d\n" \'a
```

**Decimal to ASCII**: "97" → "a"

```sh
printf '%b' $(printf '\\%03o' "97")
```

Comment: Thanks @Pablo, `wolf@linux:~$ printf "%d\n" \'a
97` is for a single char. 

What about `abc`?

I've tried `printf "%d\n" \'abc` and `printf "%d%d%d\n" \'abc` but didn't work

Comment: Try `printf "%d\n" \'a \'b \'c`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, with Perl's [`unpack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack):

```
$ echo abc | perl -lne 'print join " ", unpack("C*")'
97 98 99
```

More verbosely using `split` and `ord`,

```
$ echo abc | perl -lne 'print join " ", map { ord $_ } split //'
97 98 99
```

**Reference**: [Converting Between ASCII Characters and Values](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch01_05.htm)

Comment: Cool. It works. I was trying to up vote your answer but nothing happens