# Which tool is best in your opinion to convert decimal to ascii?

Tags: ascii

I have a problem in converting decimal to ascii or ascii to decimal. I used to convert it manually but it takes a lot of time.Please suggest a tool.

Comment: Asking for opinions is usually not within the scope of this site. However, I'm sure you would rephrase your question, or see if an existing question already covers this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ASCII to its decimal value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245360/convert-ascii-to-its-decimal-value)

Comment: What kind of tool would suit your needs? A GUI, or a command (like `echo -ne \\x$(printf %02x 65)`, or a bash function?

Comment: ANY answer is going to be subjective and you are not asking for a solution to a problem ;-) I would use command line python3 Very easy to automate reading a text file with lines that needs converting Please make a better question.

Comment: Days ago, i asked a question in regard converting decimal to ascii. I also myself  found a tool. It was so helpful . check it here. https://decimaltoascii.com/